# how to solve bad credentials spring Security?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I can't log in to my app as a user with the role `admin` or as a user with the role `user`. I always log in as a user with the role `anonymous`.

```
Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder("53cr3t");
    }
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()


        .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/rentAppPage/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/removeVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/updateVehicle").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/allUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/resultGet").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/addUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/getUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/updateUser").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/removeUserById").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/price").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/allScooter").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/allCar").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/allMotorBike").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/allBike").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/distance").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/rent").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/rent2").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/buy").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/buy2").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/thanks").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .antMatchers("/rentAppPage").hasAnyAuthority( "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()

                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                 .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        ;


        http.sessionManagement()
                //.expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html")
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login.html");
    }



}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUser;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String role;
    private String locationName;
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;


    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(IUserDAO userDAO){
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user  = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null){
            throw  new UsernameNotFoundException("User dont exist");
        }
        return new MyUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements IUserDAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public void addUser(User user){
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            tx.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            if(tx != null)tx.rollback();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        Session  session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        User user =(User) session.createQuery("FROM pl.edu.wszib.model.User WHERE username = :username" )
                .setParameter("username", username)
                .uniqueResult();
        session.close();
        return user;

    }
}
```

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        return Arrays.asList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
2021-01-18 17:05:43.545 DEBUG 4256 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@cd98cfcc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AD82C9600EFB66CF7C6F8A1BCCEEAE0D; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

i have databse in MySQL with two users first role admin second role user my role in database is ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER i my full code is here https://github.com/Conrado1212/SpringSecurityWhyCantWorkFine
can someone explain why i cant log in to app as user with role admin or user ?

Comment: and what are your debug logs telling you?

Comment: voted to close, needs debugging details and clarification of what the actual problem is.

Comment: my debugs telling me ```2021-01-18 17:05:43.545 DEBUG 4256 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@cd98cfcc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AD82C9600EFB66CF7C6F8A1BCCEEAE0D; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'```

Comment: dont write your debug logs in a comment, you have the ability to edit your question, update your question instead with your full debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the code you have posted on github and none of the code you posted in the above question is the problem. You problem is how you perform your login.

login.html

```
<form action="/authenticate" method="post" id="login" class="input-group">
     <div th:text="`enter code here`${errorMessage}" id="error-message"></div>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" th:field="*{userModel.username}"  required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter password"  name="password" th:field="*{userModel.password}"required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chech-box"><span class="span1">Remember password</span>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Here we se that the login form posts to the endpoint `/authenticate`. This is NOT the standard `/login` endpoint that spring security sets up for you automatically.

Since you are not using the the standard i find your custom endpoint.

LoginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  String authenticateUser(@ModelAttribute("userModel")User user,Model model){
    boolean authResult = this.authenticationService.authenticationUser(user);
    if(authResult){
        System.out.println("zalogowano !!");
        return "rentAppPage";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","zle dane!!!");
        model.addAttribute("userModel",new User());
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Here we see that you pass the user object into a custom written function called `authenticationUser`. So if we look in that function we find this implementation.

AuthenticationService.java

```
@Override
public boolean authenticationUser(User user){
    User userFromDb = this.userDAO.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    return userFromDb != null && userFromDb.getPassword().equals(DigestUtils.md5Hex(user.getPassword()));
}
```

All you do in this function, is to fetch the user from the database. Check if the users password matches, and then return a boolean.

If the boolean is true you return the next page.

This is **NOT** how spring security works. All of the above code is completely faulty, and its clear that no research has been done before asking here on stack overflow. How could the server know you have called that function before? it can't.

My answer to your question, is that your implementation is completely wrong, and i highly suggest you find a `getting started guide` to how form login works in spring security, because explaining how spring security works, can not be done in a simple answer.

All im going to do is to link you to the official [`Spring security FormLogin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form) documentation, and you should start reading there.

Comment: It's not necessary, and the app works with MD5. Of course, and I'm agree that MD5 is legacy and non-secured, and BCrypt is better, but a choice - what to use - is a developer dealing. In this case you are wrong, the code is workable.

Comment: and as i wrote, your question was bad and should be closed because of lack of debugging details and clarity. I wrote a speculative answer to a badly written question.

Comment: ok but when i test this without my login page i test this with login page from spring security and i cant login to app  how you explain this ?

Comment: if using spring login page then you have a different problem than you have posted here. I have looked through your code, and i will only comment on the question you have posted here. You have several faulty problems in your code, and stack overflow is not a forum where you discussion solutions. Its a Q&A site. You ask ONE specific question and you get ONE specific answer.

Comment: if you have more problems, then implement the spring login page, and debug your code, post a new question, along with e specific question, alongside steps to reproduce and with proper debugging logs. Stack overflow is your LAST resort, when asking, read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: your question has been answered. Will not post more here now.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many questions about encoder, md5, etc. But it's your choice even it's wrong )))

I run your code, if MD5 hash is correct in DB I can login. As I understand, the question is why the application does not store the state of logged in user?

Expectation:

- 1st request: call method (incognito) -> login -> call method (authorized)
- Xth request: call method -> Spring Security checks -> call method (authorized)

Reality:

- Xth request: always equals 1st

The cause that you don't change a state of Spring Security context. You call /login endpoint, check if the User is in DB, check his password and return success response. You should create an authorization and place it in the Spring Security context.

Simple example:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
String token = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
return token;
```

And in next requests use the token. How to implement the token provider there are many examples. It can be custom or better JWT.

If you don't want tokens (RESTful), you can use sessions in requests (RESTless) but it requires additional configuration.

Comment: i have authentication method ```public class AuthenticationServiceImpl implements IAuthenticationService {

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;


    public AuthenticationServiceImpl(IUserDAO userDAO){
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean authenticationUser(User user){
        User userFromDb = this.userDAO.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        return userFromDb != null && userFromDb.getPassword().equals(DigestUtils.md5Hex(user.getPassword()));
    }
}``` this method is correct i use this method in my loginController

Comment: but when i use my custom login page i can pass the login authentication method check username and password but springSecurity doesnt  see my user i dont know why i do all like in the book but i cant secure my url in page

Comment: I wanted to make a commit in different branch but cannot do that: permissions denied for me.

Comment: I added token support in simple direct way - with security filter before authorization. It checks the header Authorization (should be like 'Bearer <token>') and if it's correct, adds a User object into your session bean and you can use it in the code. Also I could not implement it with MD5, so I changed to BCrypt. And rmember - code is raw, you need to fix it, add cleaning object, change to less manual code. If you give me access I will commit changes, or contact me, I will send you archive.

Comment: In the first page after login I added a row with token (for checking),

Comment: how i can contact wiht you ?